# Is REDIS Pub/Sub apt for moderate size binary data?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe

I've got jobs that I'm planning to send to workers via [REDIS Pub/Sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub). Job involves processing an image (JPEG, 20KB-800KB, typically around 150KB).

Is it a good idea to send the image directly as the message's payload?

Comment: I wouldn't do it. This greatly increases load on your redis, there are better tools for transferring images. You could even store the image on filesystem and have nginx stream it to a worker. Performance should be comparable.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: that's actually the alternative I was considering, however I'm not sure if it is necessary. It will add complexity and extra point of faliure to my system.

Comment: Sure, it will add an extra component and an extra point of failure (which is a rather positive fact. SPOF is bad, m'kay? :) ). Nginx file streaming is very scalable. But if you use only redis, what are your actions in case the redis instance starts collapsing under load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see this as a problem at all. If you are confident your subscriber(s)/worker(s) will be able to keep up and you won't risk running out of RAM then I think this is a valid approach. I don't know if its better than nginx streaming as suggested, but being an in-memory data store redis should scale pretty close to the hardware and network limits.

Keep in mind that redis pub/sub is not "durable" so if an image is published to a channel no one is currently subscribed to it won't get picked up. The image would just go nowhere.

You could build a durable queue pretty easy using a redis List if you need durability.

Answer (score -1):

You can encode the JPEG file by base64 into string, and publish the string to the channel.

The size of send data(payload JPEG file) would be increased to about 1.5x to 2x.

Comment: no need since "Redis Strings are binary safe, this means that a Redis string can contain any kind of data, for instance a JPEG image or a serialized Ruby object." as per documentation